# Why are table statistics locked?

Tags: oracle11g, database-performance

I am confused because statistics are not gathered for some tables on many schemas.
These tables has been analyzed last time during night, I assume it had been done by job **auto optimizer stats job** which is enabled.
I realized this when try to gather statistics manually by receiving:

```
ora-20005 object statistics are locked
```

after Tuning Advisor ordered gathers statistics for long running query.

What could locked this statistics? Could be default disabled? I assume no one did this because there is no benefit of such behaviour in long term perspective.

---

After some research I found partial answer:
https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/maintaining_statistics_on_large_partitioned_tables

I also found discovered that statistic are locked for partitioned table by partitioning procedure which runs every night, there is line:

```
dbms_stats.lock_table_stats(...)
```

I wonder is good or bad practice? I suppose some time ago it was good but since Oracle 11g it has no sense at all.
I will try to introduce approach with Incremental Statistics Maintenance ([docs](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/maintaining_statistics_on_large_partitioned_tables)) instead of disabling global statistic gathering which I think is DEPRECATED idea...

Comment: What locks do you have in your database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you believe that "it has no sense at all"?

Locking statistics is neither good nor bad practice.  It all depends on why you're locking them.  Presumably, someone in the past identified some sort of problem that locking the statistics solved.  You'd need to find out what problem that was and whether it is still an issue.  If you have tables with large amounts of transient data, for example, you may want to gather statistics when the tables are relatively full and lock the statistics so that the automatic statistics gathering job doesn't accidentally run when the tables are mostly empty and cause very expensive table scans later when the tables are full.

If the problem that was being solved was that gathering global statistics on the partitioned table was slow, then potentially using incremental statistics maintenance would be a better solution.  Given that incremental statistics maintenance is not the default behavior, however, it would be incorrect to consider alternative approaches "deprecated".  Particularly when you have an existing solution that meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you for answer - you are right, my opinion on disabling the statistics was too hasty. I found out these statistics are disabled due to slow gathering in the past but in another environment where there is order of magnitude in data volume. I suppose that in our environment incremental statistics will be more efficient but I have to just check it out.